# Setting Excel power view settings from c# app

Tags: c#, .net, excel, powerview, powerbi

I have BI app that extracts data from data source and shows it in excel, i am wondering is it possible to show the data in excel directly as Power View , so is there any code to control the excel power View settings using c#.

Comment: I believe that there's currently no way to do this, due to the fact that Power View is a Silverlight object.  Check this post on MSDN for a bit more detail: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fd9e90e2-ebc5-4dfb-9eaf-a263729b8ed2/how-to-generate-powerview-model-programmatically?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to create a power view programmatically in Excel.

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)

Comment: So, isn't there an API or anything to generate *Power View* reports from code?

Comment: That's right. Its not something that is supported for power view. We are compiling customer suggestions through support.PowerBI.com. Would be really useful if you could submit a suggestion there and let us know what the overall scenario is where you'd need to generate the power views programmatically.